# Xdebug PhpStorm: Explain about the step into and step out

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I want to understand about what is step into and step out in xdebug phpstorm, and what is the difference between them, and what should i use most in debugging with xdebug phpstorm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really a Magento-related question but I am happy to answer it.

Step Into means that you will follow the code execution into the next function to fire.

Step Out is exactly the opposite. If you don't feel the need to go line by line through the function that you are currently exploring, it will execute the remainder of that code without stopping unless you have a breakpoint set somewhere.

I made a tutorials series on youtube about how to use xDebug & PhpStorm together.

There are 7 total videos in the series.
[PHPStorm / xDebug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDbF3UmV8jQ&list=PL7cMNPx-nzyiKmGE2A08S2PF5MKfBJF3n)

Comment: Wow, thanks, i'm gonna watch that videos. I was put an breakpoint but then i dont see any diffrence between step out and step in. They come in the same function which i put the breakpoint in.

Comment: Theres a button called step over. Instead of stopping at one breaking point and then jumping to the next break point, you can step down over each individual line of code, one at a time. xdebug is awesome!

Comment: Oh nice, i'm working with magento, and cant do it without xdebug .. @@

Comment: By stepping through code, you’ll rapidly advance your learning of the Magento architecture. Xdebug is essential.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your useful videos, i'll watch it later. :)

Comment: Just adding the link by Magento docs - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/docker/docker-phpstorm-debug.html